# How do I expose a webapp on :8090, even though firewall allows only :80 and :22

Tags: amazon-ec2, port-forwarding, jetty

I am a noob in Server related stuff, so bear me.

I use amazon webservices (EC2) on which I have a webapp running on jetty, which runs on port 8090. I deploy the webapp through the usual method of

`java -jar start.jar`

So then to access the app, I have to add a port in the URL, like this:

`someIP:8090/app`

But just typing `someIP` in the browser takes me to a page that shows

> It works!
>
> This is the default web page for this
>   server.
>
> The web server software is running but
>   no content has been added, yet.

which I assume is apache. I have apache, tomcat and jetty installed. What can I do so that I dont have to specify the port? Do I have to perform port-forwarding?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look into something like [mod_jk](http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/).  It will allow you to connect an Apache instance to a JAS running on a separate port.  Or, you could just setup Jetty to use port 80...

Comment: i used iptables,but in your opinion, what is a better method, iptables or mod_jk?

Comment: I think almost everybody would recommend `mod_jk`, if only because mucking with its configuration is not a system level action.  Plus, it gives you more control over port 80--you now have full access to port 80 and can forward specific contexts, instead of EVERYTHING on port 80.

Answer (score 1):

The jetty guys have a [pretty good page on running jetty on port 80, or using iptables to redirect traffic from port 80](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/port80).

Comment: I dont have a ../extras folder!

Comment: Fine, try their iptables redirect instructions instead, then.